# failed to set partition size on device when mounting RAID 0 ubuntu 18 h700

Tags: raid, desktop-environments

I am running Ubuntu 18 desktop on a dell r510 with a h700 raid card. Yes, desktop is necessary.

The h700 card makes all drives some form of raid, otherwise they are not recognized by the server, and therefor not available to the OS. I have two 1tb drives as individual raid 0s, and a large 12tb raid 0 comprised of 2tb drives. I can mount my individual 1tb raid 0 drives no problem. However, when I try to mount my 12tb raid 0, I get the following error

Failed to set partition size on device. Unable to satisfy all constraints on the partition.

Any thoughts on how to get around this?

I have tried mounting using gparted and sudo mount. I get the following error with sudo mount:

wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.

I have installed nfs-common and cifs-utils.

****resolved
I successfully mounted a smaller partition called Linux Raid within the 12tb raid0, and then expanded it to consume the 12tb once mounted.

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu Core 18? or Ubuntu 18.04 LTS? or Ubuntu 18.10?   Ubuntu Core 18 is usually used headless (which possibly explains your mentioning desktop as necessary).

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 lts